# auto populate input field based on lookup

Tags: apex, visualforce, contact

I have a visualforce page. Where  am using contact as standard object.

- My 1st inputfield is lookup of contact
- 2nd & 3rd inputfields are first and lastname of the contact object.

Now based on the particular contact selected from lookup...i need to auto-populated the first and lastname inputfield in visualpage before clicking the save button.

Comment: Have you already tried writing some code ? - it would be great if you could include that in your question.

Comment: It would be great to have a code snippet related to your problem. You can use the Apex rerender event based on the first inputfield...

Comment: no i havent try with the code...i am new salesforce so its getting difficult for me to proceed. if u could help me with the code.
also can i auto populate any inputfield by lookup or we must use only inputtext to auto populate by lookup.